# I get User not recognised error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

When I am doing pip install pytesseract. I get following error in Jupyter Notebook:

> C:\users\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have connected all paths still in the same way.

I am running on Windows

How do I solve this?

Comment: try `pip` in normal console/terminal/cmd.exe instead of jupyter

Answer (score 0):

Open `Anaconda Prompt` from the start menu.

And then install your package using `pip install package_name`

Then start Jupyter Notebook using the command `jupyter notebook` in the same console. I hope it works!